# How to generate the list of route segment parameters for every pokemon using generateStaticParams in Next.js 13?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, web-frontend, static-data, next.js13

I am trying to use Nextjs 13's `generateStaticParams` to render static data into my web page. How do I generate the list of routes like `/pokemon/[pokemonName]` for every pokemon name using the `generateStaticParams` without providing hard-coded pokemon name (for example here I put `"charmander"` as argument for `fetchData` and then it generate route just for charmander)?

```
export const generateStaticParams = async (): Promise<PageParams[]> => {
  const res = await fetchData("charmander");

  return [
    {
      pokemonName: res?.data.pokemon.name,
    },
  ];
};
```

Fetching pokemon moves from graphQL-pokeAPI:

```
const fetchData = async (pokemonName: string) => {
  const POKEMON_MOVES = `
  query pokemon($name: String!) {
      pokemon(name: $name) {
        id
        name
        sprites {
          front_default
        }
        moves {
          move {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `;

  const res = await fetch("https://graphql-pokeapi.graphcdn.app/", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: POKEMON_MOVES,
      variables: { name: pokemonName },
    }),
  });

  const moves = await res.json();
  return moves;
};
```

```
export default function SpecificPokemon({ params }) {
  const { pokemonName } = params;
  const pokemonData = use(fetchData(pokemonName));

  return (<h1>{pokemonName}</h1>...)
};
```

In the Nextjs13 beta docs, it said that `generateStaticParams` doesn't require any context parameters. So I can't pass `pokemonName` into `generateStaticParams` like this, right?

```
export const generateStaticParams = async (pokemonName: string) => {
  const res = await fetchData(pokemonName);
```

I tried to just write `fetchData("")` and the page just blank. Also, it would be too many to write like this:

```
return [
    { pokemonName: "bulbasaur" },
    { pokemonName: "ivysaur" },
    { pokemonName: "venusaur" },
  ];
```

Also, is this due to my lack of JS / Next13 concept understanding?

Answer (score 0):

They actually have a feature called [getStaticPaths](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-paths) which was specifically designed for this.  You can easily make a call to a pokemon api and parse the response into getStaticPaths at run to generate the static paths you want to use.  I encourage you to play with the documentation more, that team did a killer job with them.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: He's using the new App directory beta so it is slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

```
export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const posts = await getPosts();

  return posts.map((post) => ({
    slug: post.slug,
  })
 );
}
```

Here's an example for a posts table - but basically you get all the posts or in your case Pokemon, and map the names to an array.

I'm not sure if there's a better way of handling it but that should point you in the right direction. I'm still reading up on NextJS and especially the new Beta myself, so take with a pinch of salt.